# I am trying to convert a column str to a float in a Data Frame using Python 2

Tags: python, database, data-mining

Im new to data analysis and looking for help.I am creating my Knn algorithm from scratch using python.I need to convert one of the columns of my data Frame which is a str to a float.I am using python 2.This is how the data Frame look.

```
    sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width CLASS_LABEL
0            6.1          2.9           4.7          1.4  versicolor
1            6.0          2.7           5.1          1.6  versicolor
2            5.4          3.0           4.5          1.5  versicolor
3            5.6          2.5           3.9          1.1  versicolor
```

I have to convert the CLASS_LABEL column str to a float. Thanks in advance!

```
from scipy.io import arff
from io import StringIO
import scipy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
train,meta = arff.loadarff(open('train.arff', 'r'))
train = pd.DataFrame(train)
print(train)
print(type(train))
train.CLASS_LABEL = train.CLASS_LABEL.astype('float64')
print(train['CLASS_LABEL'])
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-9b34833d2225> in <module>()
      2 # train.head()
      3 # print(type(train))
----> 4 train.CLASS_LABEL = train.CLASS_LABEL.astype('float64')
      5 print(train['CLASS_LABEL'])

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    176                 else:
    177                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 178             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    179         return wrapper
    180     return _deprecate_kwarg

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)
   4999             # else, only a single dtype is given
   5000             new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,
-> 5001                                          **kwargs)
   5002             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
   5003 

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in astype(self, dtype, **kwargs)
   3712 
   3713     def astype(self, dtype, **kwargs):
-> 3714         return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
   3715 
   3716     def convert(self, **kwargs):

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate, **kwargs)
   3579 
   3580             kwargs['mgr'] = self
-> 3581             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
   3582             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
   3583 

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    573     def astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None, **kwargs):
    574         return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors, values=values,
--> 575                             **kwargs)
    576 
    577     def _astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None,

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in _astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, klass, mgr, **kwargs)
    662 
    663                 # _astype_nansafe works fine with 1-d only
--> 664                 values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
    665                 values = values.reshape(self.shape)
    666 

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.pyc in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy)
    728 
    729     if copy:
--> 730         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
    731     return arr.view(dtype)
    732 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: setosa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is that you're trying to convert a string (like `setosa`) into a float, which obviously isn't possible because that's not a number.

If you want to map the string categories into numbers you can use:

`train["CLASS_LABEL"] = train["CLASS_LABEL"].factorize()[0]`

this will turn your strings into numerical categories